# php mysql jquery : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have created two programs, one is html which contains the Data Table Layout and second is PHP file which contains the Object based PHP program.

When I am running, I am getting

**Failed to load resource: the server http://localhost/exp/example.php?p=view responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

And I am unable to find the error in PHP script as I am starter. Please take a look at below programs and help me out with the solution.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tracker</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style type="text/css">
        .modal-dialog, .modal-content{
        z-index:1051;
        }
    </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://markcell.github.io/jquery-tabledit/assets/js/prettify.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tabledit.js"></script>


</head>
<body onload="viewData()">

    <div class="container">

        <br>
        <br>
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="usertrackertable">
                    <thead class="tabledit-toolbar-column">
                        <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Ticket No</th>
                        <th>Full Name</th>
                        <th>Emp Id</th>
                        <th>Mail</th>
                        <th>Member Type</th>
                        <th>Location</th>
                        <th>Request Type</th>
                        <th>Asset Type</th>
                        <th>Asset No</th>
                        <th>Serial No</th>
                        <th>Model</th>
                        <th>Comments</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th class=tabledit-toolbar-column></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">


            function viewData(){
                $.ajax({
                    url:'example.php?p=view',
                    method: 'GET'
                }).done(function(data){
                    $('usertrackertable').html(data)
                    tableData()

                })

            }

            function tableData(){

                $('#usertrackertable').Tabledit({
                    url: 'example.php',
                    columns: {
                        identifier: [0, 'id'],
                        editable: [[1, 'Ticket No'], [2, 'firstname'], [3, 'lastname']]
                    }
                }); 


            }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**example.php**

```
<?php

// Basic example of PHP script to handle with jQuery-Tabledit plug-in.
// Note that is just an example. Should take precautions such as filtering the input data.

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$mysqli = mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'admin', 'ham');



if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo json_encode(array('mysqli' => 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()));
  exit;
}

$page= isset($_GET['p'])? $_GET['p'] : '' ;

if($page=='view'){

    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT id, ticket_no, full_name, emp_id, emp_mail, member_type, member_location, request_type, asset_type, asset_number, serial_number, asset_model_number, remarks_comments, timestamp, status FROM HAMTRACKER WHERE is_flagged != '1';");
    while($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){
        ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['id']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['ticket_no'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['full_name']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['emp_id']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['emp_mail']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['member_type']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['member_location'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['request_type']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['asset_type'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['asset_number'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['serial_number']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['asset_model_number']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['remarks_comments']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['timestamp']  ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['status']  ?></td>
        </tr>
            <?php
    }
}else{




$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);




if ($input['action'] === 'edit') {
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE hamtracker SET ticket_no='" . $input['tickettb'] . "',
    full_name='" . $input['fullnametb'] . "',
    emp_id='" . $input['employeeidtb'] . "' ,
    emp_mail='" . $input['emailtb'] . "',
    member_type='" . $input['selectmembertypedd'] . "',
    member_location='" . $input['selectmemberlocationdd'] . "',
    request_type='" . $input['selectrequesttypedd'] . "',
    asset_type='" . $input['selectassettypedd'] . "',
    asset_number='" . $input['assetnumbertb'] . "',
    serial_number='" . $input['serialnumbertb'] . "',
    asset_model_number='" . $input['selectassetmodelnumberdd'] . "',
    remarks_comments='" . $input['remarkstb'] . "',
    timestamp= default,
    status='" . $input['status'] . "' WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'");



} else if ($input['action'] === 'delete') {
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE hamtracker SET is_flagged=1 WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'");
} else if ($input['action'] === 'restore') {
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE hamtracker SET is_flagged=0 WHERE id='" . $input['id'] . "'");
}

mysqli_close($mysqli);



echo json_encode($input);
}



?>
```

Comment: Are you talking about  echo json_encode(array('mysqli' => 'Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error()));

Comment: What is INPUT_POST?

Comment: It's probably in one of the SQL statements. What I always do is a var_dump of the created statement and execute it in Workbench to validate if any errors occur. UPDATE hamtracker SET ticket_no... is a good candidate.

Comment: the code you posted doesn't show any errors

Comment: Thanks you @Gerard, I have executed those Queries in the phpmyadmin and running well without any error. Some where i have done some mistake, thats why in table the datas are not populating.

Comment: use `new` with `mysqli` in your `PHP`

Comment: @julekgwa you're the (wo)man

Comment: @julekgwa I tried this earlier, where i was getting ***{"mysqli":"Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"*** error.

Comment: yes your password or username is wrong

Comment: @julekgwa with same password I am able to login to phpmyadmin workbench.

Comment: @KeViN see this post https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: @Gerard; @julekgwa : Please take a look at the image, https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6sHIVf1SfYzekVkbXlTQlZXXzg

Comment: hi all, Barely need your help, please help me out on this.